# Display a error message according to the no. of tries?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to java and Android. In the below snippet,I am displaying a error message when the username & the Password is incorrect.Now i need to add some extra information in the error message after 2 wrong tries.
If i need to set a Counter to identify the tries ?
How can i do it ?

```
public void testBadCredentials() throws Exception {
    RestClientFactoryTest.setPrefixAllInstances("login-failure");
    XMLRPCFactoryTest.setPrefixAllInstances("login-failure");
    mSolo.enterText(0, "test"); //username 
    mSolo.enterText(1, "test"); //password
    mSolo.clickOnText(mSolo.getString(R.string.sign_in));
    boolean errorMessageFound = mSolo.searchText(mSolo.getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrect));
    assertTrue("Error message not found", errorMessageFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static n0_attamp = 0;
public void testBadCredentials() throws Exception {
n0_attamp++;
RestClientFactoryTest.setPrefixAllInstances("login-failure");
XMLRPCFactoryTest.setPrefixAllInstances("login-failure");
mSolo.enterText(0, "test"); //username 
mSolo.enterText(1, "test"); //password
mSolo.clickOnText(mSolo.getString(R.string.sign_in));
boolean errorMessageFound = mSolo.searchText(mSolo.getString(R.string.username_or_password_incorrect));
if(n0_attamp = 3)
{ 
  assertTrue("3rd try", errorMessageFound);
  //reinitialize counter
   n0_attamp = 0; 
 }
 else
assertTrue("Error message not found", errorMessageFound);
}
```